# To determine the boundaries of pieces of lands and then their lengths

Tags: image-processing

**Hello!!** I am trying to determine the real lengths of boundaries of pieces of lands frm an aerial image.Having applied **canny method** to detect the boudaries, i then applied **Hough transformation** to detect the straight lines of the boundaries **(Boundaries are assumed to be straight lines here)**.Distances were calculated also but the problem are 1. Not all boundaries were detected by the Hough Transformation.2.Calculated distances could not be ascertained to any particular line on the image, because there are many lines defining the boundaries of the pieces of lands, so i dont know which measurement belongs to which line on the image. Pls assist.

Answer (score 0):

If it is for a one-time calculation (and for a relatively small area) you might be better off digitizing the polygons manually and using a GIS package to calculate their lengths. Alternatively, if your lines are clean enough, you could convert them back to vector polygons; you may not get all the parcels, but at least then you have a way of calculating lengths and of attaching them to specific parcels of land.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i am trying to find the solution using Image processing techniques as an alternative to the GIS method. So i have been trying to see how i can figure out your altenative answer practically,that is converting image to vector polygons but no much progress.Any further guidance pls?

Comment: GDAL/OGR has Python bindings, it is a library for reading, writing and processing raster and vector data. Combined with Numpy or Scipy, it can perform such analysis. I didn't suggest this in the answer because you had not specified a programming language in your tags...

Comment: Sorry for being too reserved with my question.I appreciate your effort in providing solutions to my problem.However, i am trying to use Matlab, but i dont know if it is not feasible in this case.So any alternative guidance using Matlab apart from the Hough Transform i tried before? Once again,any further guidance pls?